# Problema de segurança ao fazer upload

Tags: php, segurança, upload

Tenho uma aplicação construída com CodeIgniter que realiza o upload de arquivos de imagem para um diretório no servidor. Executando no localhost, funciona perfeitamente. Quando no servidor oficial, é retornado um erro ao tentar transferir o arquivo. Suspeitando de falta de permissão na pasta, solicitei à pessoa que cuida do servidor para liberar o acesso ao diretório. Esta pessoa disse que haveria um risco de segurança e pediu que eu encontrasse um modo alternativo de upload.

A pergunta é: como efetuar o upload de arquivos sem ter de abrir todas as defesas do servidor? 
Abaixo segue o código da view.

HTML:

```
 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="Table11">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>               
           <br />
           <div id="resposta" style="width: 120px; height: 60px; border: thin dashed #555;">

           </div>
           <br />
           <form name="formUpload" id="formUpload" method="post">
                <span class="label" id="Label14">Banner:</span>
                <label><input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" size="45" style="font-size: 11px; " /></label>
                 <br />
                 <progress value="0" max="100"></progress><span id="porcentagem">0%</span>
                 <br />
                 <input type = "button" value="Enviar Banner" onclick="enviarBanner()" style="margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #555; cursor: pointer; font-size: 12px;" />
              </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function enviarBanner(){
            if($.trim($('#descBanner').val()) === ""){
                alert("Campo DesciÃ§ao Ã© Obrigatorio");
                $('#descBanner').focus();
                return;
            }
            arquiv = $('#arquivo').val();
            $('#formUpload').ajaxForm({     
                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    $('progress').attr('value',percentComplete);
                    $('#porcentagem').html(percentComplete+'%');
                },  
                success: function(data) {
                    $('progress').attr('value','100');
                    $('#porcentagem').html('100%'); 
                    if(data.sucesso === true){
                        enviado = true;
                        $('#resposta').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>'+ data.msg +'" width="120" height="60" />'); 
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#resposta').html(data.msg);
                    }                
                },
                error : function(){
                    $('#resposta').html('Erro ao enviar requisiÃ§Ã£o!');
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '<?php echo base_url()?>areaRestrita/banners/imgUpload',
                resetForm: true
            }).submit();
            enviado = true;
        }
</script>
```

Abaixo segue  a função de upload:

```
function imgUpload(){

           $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

           $tipos = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'psd', 'bmp');

           $enviar = $this->uploadFile($arquivo, 'Imagens/banners/', $tipos);

       }

function uploadFile($arquivo, $pasta, $tipos, $nome = null){
$nomeOriginal = "";
    if(isset($arquivo)){
        $infos = explode(".", $arquivo["name"]);
        if(!$nome){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($infos) - 1; $i++){
                $nomeOriginal = $nomeOriginal . $infos[$i] . ".";
            }
        }
        else{
            $nomeOriginal = $nome . ".";
        }
        $tipoArquivo = $infos[count($infos) - 1];
        $tipoPermitido = false;
        foreach($tipos as $tipo){
            if(strtolower($tipoArquivo) == strtolower($tipo)){
                $tipoPermitido = true;
            }
        }
        if(!$tipoPermitido){
            $retorno["erro"] = "Tipo nÃ£o permitido";

        }
        else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'], $pasta . $nomeOriginal . $tipoArquivo)){

                $retorno["caminho"] = $pasta . $nomeOriginal . $tipoArquivo;
            }
            else{

                $retorno["erro"] = "Erro ao fazer upload";

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $retorno["erro"] = "Arquivo nao setado";

    }

    return $retorno;
}
```

Comment: Aonde está o código em que você usa essa função `uploadFile`?

Comment: A função imgUpload(), chamada no código JavaScript faz algumas verificações e chama, por sua vez, a função uploadFile, que é exibida acima.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada no SO inglês http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256172/what-is-the-most-secure-method-for-uploading-a-file :)

Comment: para prosseguir com upload precisa das permissões... que servidor é esse que não permite e ainda manda procurar alternativa? rsrsrs Uma alternativa é enviar os arquivos via FTP usando as funções ftp do php, outra alternativa é trocar de servidor.

Comment: O "problema" de permissão está mais ligado com a forma como o servidor foi configurado. O seu usuário deve estar no mesmo grupo do usuário que roda o Apache (ou outro servidor web). Assim, é possível usar permissão 775 em vez de 777.

Comment: O administrador do servidor está certo. Você vai incluir um risco de segurança grave. O padrão sugerido para esses casos é gravar a imagem em uma base de dados, como *MySQL* ou *SQL Server*.

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde, essa pergunta é bem relativa, mas o que pode ser feito é o seguinte: dar permissão de "escrita" para o proprietários do diretório (quer poderá ser você) onde só irá conter as imagens (isso você vê com o pessoal que cuida do server) e adicionar também um arquivo ".htaccess" para não deixar acessar a raiz do pasta (tipo mostrando o nome de todos os arquivos no browser).

É comum ter um diretório só para imagens e nem por isso precisa quebrar a segurança do servidor.

Dica de segurança: Salve suas imagens com nomes criptografados no servidor (no banco de dados você pode salvar o nome original junto a criptografia do arquivo) e quando for puxar as imagens desse diretório, atente-se a ataques do "Directory Transversal", que no lugar da imagem seria mais ou menos isso:

https://seusite.com.br?imagem=../../../../../etc/passwd